# HMap with case objects as keys

Tags: scala, shapeless, case-class

I am trying to achieve something with Shapeless' HMap, but am not sure whether this is possible and if it is, then how would I go about it.

I want to use HMap as a map of user preferences where values can be of different types. This is what I mean:

```scala
object UserPreferences {
  sealed abstract class BooleanPreference
  case object IsStudent extends BooleanPreference
  case object SubscribedToNotifications extends BooleanPreference

  sealed abstract class StringPreference
  case object Language extends StringPreference

  class UserPreference[K, V]
  implicit val booleanPreferenceToBoolean = new UserPreference[BooleanPreference, Boolean]
  implicit val stringPreferenceToString = new PartialClientPref[StringPreferenceKey, String]
}
```

Then later on I have this map as a method argument:

```scala
import UserPreferences._

def someMethod(userPreferences: HMap[UserPreference]) {
  val userLanguage = userPreferences(Language)
}
```

The last code snippet doesn't compile. First it complaints about missing implicit parameter, but when I add `stringPreferenceToString` explicitly the compiler indicates that it requires `UserPreference[UserPreferences.Language.type, NotInferredV]` but found `UserPreference[StringPreference, String]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to widen `Language` to a `StringPreference` and `import userPreferences._`.

```scala
import UserPreferences._

def someMethod(userPreferences: HMap[UserPreference]) {
  import userPreferences._
  val userLanguage = userPreferences(Language: StringPreference)
}
```

Comment: Thanks @yangzai, I learned something. Too bad it is a bit lengthy.

Comment: @vasigorc you don't need `import userPreferences._` with `userPreferences.get`. It's also safer since it returns a `None` if there's no matching key.